# Is there a rhyming dictionary I can run on the OSX command line?

Tags: software-recommendation, homebrew

Is there a rhyming dictionary I can run on the OSX command line?

I found these but don't know how to get them running on my Mac:

- https://trac.macports.org/ticket/39651
- http://osl.no.distfiles.macports.org/rhyme/
- https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhyme

It looks like the rhyme package is for Ubuntu. How can I get it working on OSX?

Comment: Did you try installing it via macports?   (I didn't see a homebrew package available)

Comment: MacPorts! That worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together a Homebrew tap for Rhyme. Please see:

https://github.com/shaunplee/homebrew-rhyme

Comment: I get `Error: No such file or directory - rhyme`:

Comment: Hmm. This is my first time writing a Homebrew formula. Would you mind helping me debug by sending the output of `brew install --verbose rhyme`? (opening an issue in the github repo might be a cleaner place for this conversation) Thanks!

Comment: Sure! Here you go: https://gist.github.com/73504e929b28632295f2cf1d32e14386

Comment: Interesting. It looks like it's failing because can't find `readline.h` and my original version of the formula didn't actually use the Homebrew copy of `readline`. I've edited the formula to use that instead. Try `brew update` and then `brew install rhyme`

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php)
2. $ port install rhyme

Source: @skarface

Comment: I now have Homebrew installed and rhyme stopped working. Is there a way to reinstall it without messing up my Homebrew install? I know you're not supposed to have both Homebrew and MacPorts installed at the same time.